# How do I prevent a numpy ndarray column from being converted to string when saving a Pandas DataFrame to csv?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, arraylist, numpy-ndarray

I have an DataFrame which is including an "ID" column and "Vector"(which includes (1,500) sized arrays) column. I have to save the DF as csv. When I convert the saved csv to DF again; the array becomes string and I could not use it with the functions anymore.

For example before saving the DF vector column is like:

```
>>DataFrame_example["Vector"][0]
Out:

array([[-4.51561287e-02, -5.02060959e-03,  1.01038935e-02,
        -3.24810972e-03,  8.50208327e-02, -3.12430300e-02,
        -3.06447037e-02, -6.82420060e-02,  4.08798642e-02
             ...........................................
        -6.08731210e-02,  4.24617827e-02,  2.90670991e-02,
         1.87119041e-02,  5.67540973e-02,  4.65381369e-02,
         3.42479758e-02,  9.88676678e-03, -1.62497200e-02,
         1.46159781e-02, -6.39008060e-02]], dtype=float32)


>>type(DataFrame_example["Vector"][0])
Out: numpy.ndarray
```

But after saving as csv and read it again same block output becomes;

```
>>DataFrame_example["Vector"][0]

'[[-4.51561287e-02 -5.02060959e-03  1.01038935e-02 -3.24810972e-03\n   8.50208327e-02 -3.12430300e-02 -3.06447037e-02 -6.82420060e-02\n   4.08798642e-02  2.49120360e-03 -6.40684515e-02  
 ............................................................................................
-5.22072986e-02\n   6.16791770e-02 -8.88353493e-03  1.65628344e-02 -5.95084354e-02\n  -8.45786110e-02 -8.65871832e-03  3.98499370e-02 -3.41838486e-02\n  -2.02250257e-02  5.18149361e-02 -5.80132604e-02  7.66506651e-03\n  -5.49656115e-02 -6.08731210e-02  4.24617827e-02  2.90670991e-02\n   1.87119041e-02  5.67540973e-02  4.65381369e-02  3.42479758e-02\n   9.88676678e-03 -1.62497200e-02  1.46159781e-02 -6.39008060e-02]]'
```

How can I keep the format, any help would appreciated.

I am saving the DF in csv format;

```
compression_opts = dict(method='zip',
                        archive_name=save_name+'.csv')
DataFrame_example.to_csv(save_name+'.zip', index=False,
          compression=compression_opts)
```

I am reading it with;

```
DataFrame_example=read_csv("example.csv")
```

I have triedreading it with deliiter="," or sep="," also.

Comment: Can you use `.to_parquet()` / `.read_parquet()` instead?

Comment: If you don't need explicitely a csv, you can consider saving as a pickle file instead to keep the typing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html) instead:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4], 'b' : [np.array([5,6,7,8]), np.array([5,6,7,8]),np.array([5,6,7,8]),np.array([5,6,7,8])]})

#   a             b
#0  1  [5, 6, 7, 8]
#1  2  [5, 6, 7, 8]
#2  3  [5, 6, 7, 8]
#3  4  [5, 6, 7, 8]

type(df.b[0])
#<class 'numpy.ndarray'>

df.to_pickle("out.txt")

new = pd.read_pickle("out.txt")
type(new.b[0])
#<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to strip the brackets from that string, and split the result by spaces. This will give you an array of strings that you can cast to floats.

```py
bracket_strip = str.maketrans("","","[]")

new_column = []
for vector in DataFrame_example.vector:
    print(vector)
    vector = vector.translate(bracket_strip).split(" ")

    new_vector = []
    for val in vector: 
        new_vector.append(float(val))

    new_column.append(new_vector)

DataFrame_example.vector = new_column
```

Something like that should do the trick. I just changed the variable names to yours.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a .csv file, then I would suggest that you convert to the corresponding datatype on read using the dtype argument :

> **dtypeType** name or dict of column -> type, optional
> Data type for data or columns. E.g. {‘a’: np.float64, ‘b’: np.int32, ‘c’: ‘Int64’} Use str or object together with suitable na_values settings to preserve and not interpret dtype. If converters are specified, they will be applied INSTEAD of dtype conversion.

Otherwise, you should save your data using another type of file (parquet, pickel...). This can be achieved using pandas : [pandas to_parquet](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet.html).

```
df.to_parquet('df.parquet.gzip',
              compression='gzip')  
pd.read_parquet('df.parquet.gzip')
```

The latter is often a better option performance-wise!